How to generate a palette in Angular Material 3 with a specific primary color
I need to generate a palette in Angular Material 3 to implement a theme with a specific primary color. The buttons and some other controls should be this specific color. E.g. #C9007E. I'm following the official guide to generate the palette:
> ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme
? What HEX color should be used to generate the M3 theme? It will represent your primary color palette. (ex. #ffffff) #C9007E
...

Unfortunately, the generated palette doesn't contain the color I need. How can I generate the palette so that the primary color (as I understand hue 40 in the palette) will be the color that I need?
// This file was generated by running 'ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme'.
// Proceed with caution if making changes to this file.

@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

// Note: Color palettes are generated from primary: #C9007E
$_palettes: (
  primary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #3d0023,
    20: #63003c,
    25: #770049,
    30: #8c0056,
    35: #a10064,
    40: #b70072,
    50: #dd218d,
    60: #ff43a8,
    70: #ff82bb,
    80: #ffb0cf,
    90: #ffd8e5,
    95: #ffecf1,
    98: #fff8f8,
    99: #fffbff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  ...


I am running into the same issue.

Same.  Our designer wants our buttons to be a specific color.  But running the theme generator, it produces everything BUT that color.  Very frustrating.  She wants us to dump M3 entirely as a result.  (Currently looking at importing variables from Figma to compensate.)  Is there a way to choose the seed so that the desired color is produced as the button face?

Got the same problem and for now use the following code where #33ba60 is my primary color:
@use 'sass:color';

  primary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 40) * 30),
    20: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 40) * 20),
    25: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 40) * 15),
    30: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 40) * 10),
    35: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 40) * 5),
    40: #33ba60,
    50: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 10),
    60: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 20),
    70: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 30),
    80: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 40),
    90: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 50),
    95: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 55),
    98: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 58),
    99: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 60) * 59),
    100: #ffffff,
  ),

For a dark theme hue 80 is used so I use this instead of the above:
  primary-dark: (
    0: #000000,
    10: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 70),
    20: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 60),
    25: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 55),
    30: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 50),
    35: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 45),
    40: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 40),
    50: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 30),
    60: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 20),
    70: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: -(100% / 80) * 10),
    80: #33ba60,
    90: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 20) * 10),
    95: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 20) * 15),
    98: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 20) * 18),
    99: color.scale(#33ba60, $lightness: (100% / 20) * 19),
    100: #ffffff,
  ),


Hi, do you have an example of how to create an m3 palette by hand to then reference it in the light/dark define theme (instead of built-in ones)?
@ use "@angular/material" as mat;
@ use "./app/core/layout/layout.component.theme" as layout-theme;
@ include mat.core();
$light-theme: mat.define-theme(
(
color: (
primary: mat.$azure-palette,
tertiary: mat.$blue-palette,
),
)
);
$dark-theme: mat.define-theme(
(
color: (
theme-type: dark,
primary: mat.$magenta-palette,
tertiary: mat.$violet-palette,
),
)
);

@bbcooper Use the command listed in the OP to generate an M3 theme and you can customize that to your liking.

Thanks, I just did that. I am a bit confused about the concepts. Six palettes were generated with the ng generate @ angular/material:m3-theme. Both light and dark themes reference the same two palettes (primary: $_primary, tertiary: $_tertiary). Before going into changing the palettes to reflect brand colors, I'd like to understand the concept of how colors are picked for each theme. I have a working example of how switching works with pre-defined m3 palettes, where each theme gets distinct pairs of palettes (azure and blue for light) and (magenta and violet for dark).
